# How to get user profile in twitter using outh after getting access token?

Tags: ios, twitter-oauth

I have followed tutorial http://codegerms.com/login-with-twitter-example-with-ios-tutorial-using-oauth/ to get access token using outh for twitter.
Now how can i get user profile info using access token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

follow the tutorial of getting user data using the access token, Tutorial is available on the same site
http://codegerms.com/get-user-info-data-twitter-api-example-ios-objective-c/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it by without using third party library then, Have a look at https://dev.twitter.com/rest/tools/console, twitter documentation.

Or else STTwitter is an excellent library for this. You can have a look at this 
[Github Link to STTwitter](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter)

You can get profile,Favorites,Share easily

Answer (score 0):

try this one with **tweetsharp.dll**

```
string oauth_consumer_key = "your key";
string oauth_consumer_secret = "your secret";

TwitterService tweetservice = new TwitterService(oauth_consumer_key, oauth_consumer_secret);//tweet service you will get from tweetsharp dll
string token = "your token";

string tokenSecret = "your token secret";

tweetservice.AuthenticateWith(token, tokenSecret);
var tweet = tweetservice.GetUserProfile(new GetUserProfileOptions() { IncludeEntities = false, SkipStatus = false });
```

Comment: I checked her question tags only after posting my answer. Anyway this will give her some idea about how do we access user profiles in .net. So may be by using STTwitter which Janmenjaya mentioned in his answer can achieve her result in this way.